# IOS Objective C. EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT). Can't reproduce crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I received a crash log with an error which I can't reproduce. Only information I got was that it happened after login, so I guess that it was on main screen. Any ideas if that log contains useful information?

```
Incident Identifier: xx-1698-4F90-BFE4-xx
CrashReporter Key:   xxx
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             aaa [10980]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1A877BC6-4BEF-4EC0-8734-9B1A8A51A0AB/aaa.app/aaa
Identifier:          aaa.ios
Version:             2 (1.02)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-03-01 10:10:04.04 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-03-01 10:09:19.19 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x180e45900 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1804b3f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x180d341a8 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 324
3   CoreFoundation                  0x180d34040 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 64
4   app_name                        0x100056ef8 0x100040000 + 93944
5   app_name                        0x100057904 0x100040000 + 96516
6   UIKit                           0x185b380c0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
7   UIKit                           0x185bf7da8 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72
8   UIKit                           0x185bf7c80 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 416
9   UIKit                           0x185bf6ec8 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 144
10  UIKit                           0x185bf6a6c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868
11  UIKit                           0x185bf6694 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
12  UIKit                           0x185bf65fc -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
13  UIKit                           0x185b33778 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
14  QuartzCore                      0x183542b2c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
15  QuartzCore                      0x18353d738 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
16  QuartzCore                      0x18353d5f8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
17  QuartzCore                      0x18353cc94 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
18  QuartzCore                      0x18353c9dc CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
19  QuartzCore                      0x1835360cc CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
20  CoreFoundation                  0x180dfc588 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
21  CoreFoundation                  0x180dfa32c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
22  CoreFoundation                  0x180dfa75c __CFRunLoopRun + 928
23  CoreFoundation                  0x180d29680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
24  GraphicsServices                0x182238088 GSEventRunModal + 180
25  UIKit                           0x185ba0d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
26  app_name                        0x1000780c4 0x100040000 + 229572
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x1808ca8b8 start + 4
```

Comment: there must be adding nil value in dictionary somewhere

Comment: so creating an empty (unused later) dictionary might be the issue ?

Comment: nope some value must be nil for any key

Comment: could be some incorrect settings in the xib results in this, as I can see things happened right after `-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired]` and it's `NSDictionary`/`NSPlaceholderDictionary` related.

Comment: It would be easier to figure out if you had symbolicated values for frame #4.